# Why Isn't the MySQL Index Immediately Available?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

We are in the process of moving from AWS RDS MySQL 5 to AWS RDS MySQL 8. We have a script that runs a few dozen queries. The last few look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_right_table ADD INDEX (col_a, col_b), ADD INDEX (col_c);
UPDATE my_left_table SET my_var=1 WHERE concat(col_a, col_b) in (SELECT col_c FROM my_right_table);
```

This works fine in MySQL 5 as is, and the 2nd query runs in seconds.

In MySQL 8 the 2nd query takes 20 minutes.

After much fiddling I have determined that if I throw a sleep in between the two queries, the 2nd query again runs in just seconds.

```
ALTER TABLE my_right_table ADD INDEX (col_a, col_b), ADD INDEX (col_c);
SELECT SLEEP(30);
UPDATE my_left_table SET my_var=1 WHERE concat(col_a, col_b) in (SELECT col_c FROM my_right_table);
```

Is there something about MySQL 8 that is different regarding index creation? Is it asynchronous or something?

Is the fact that it works on MySQL 5 just a fluke?

Should the index be available immediately after creating it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [multi-table UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) rather than a subquery?

Comment: How big is the table?  What is the time from _start_ of the Alter until the _end_ of the Update?

Comment: @RickJames ~3,000 rows, not very big. The ALTER statement takes less than a second, which is why I don't understand why the query doesn't use the index immediately after.

Comment: Build a test case without the CONCAT and file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com